# Store Variable in Session Meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Can anyone fix the code below so the variable `nickname` is stored in the session?

```
Template.nicknameForm.events({
    'click .js-set-nickname':function(){

        Session.set(nickname);

        var nickname = $('#nickname-input').val();

    }    
});
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html:

```js
Template.nicknameForm.events({
    'click .js-set-nickname':function(){
        var nickname = $('#nickname-input').val();
        Session.set('nickname', nickname);
    }    
});
```

Note that you seem to be misunderstanding how `Session` works. So please read the docs. In particular, be aware that there is no such thing as "storing a variable in the session". You can't just refer to the variable `nickname` to retrieve the value. You'll need to use `const nickname = Session.get('nickname')` to restore it on a page-load.

Comment: Thanks, i now need to return the value so how would i do that in this template header?

    Template.header.helpers({
        nickname:function(){
            // put something in here...
        },
    });

Comment: Sorry but this way of helping really doesn't scale. If you are not willing to learn the basics of meteor, then you won't be able to get very far with it. The tutorials are a great source, and the documentation, that I referred you to, is a must-read.

Comment: Figured it out. 

nickname:function(){
            return Session.get('nickname');
        },

Comment: Please don't forget to accept the answer and upvote if it was helpful to you.